# Windows Task Scheduler - result code 0xC000005

Tags: windows-server-2008-r2, task-scheduler

I created Task in Windows Task Scheduler which runs every day at 9:00 AM. I configured it to run using SYSTEM account and run whether user is logged or not. I'm 100% sure, that action is pointing to proper file and all parameters are correct (I check it running program by hand).

Why I'm still receiving bad result?

Comment: Yes, I noticed, that my application accessed to another process without sufficient privileges. Thank you for answer and this question can be closed.

Comment: Heh, no but problem is solved ;)

Answer (score 4):

Figured I'd convert my comment to an answer since the comment basically told you what you needed to know to solve the problem.

`0xc0000005` represents a generic access violation error. This can occur for many different reasons. There is not enough information here to tell definitively what went wrong. For instance, it is possible (though unlikely) to deny the SYSTEM account to a particular path on the file system through ACLs. It could also be the application attempting to access another process's private memory without first enabling the proper system privileges, or trying to execute code in pages of memory marked as no-execute... etc., etc.,